# Want to be able to install and use Ubuntu and select between it and Win 8 on the same PC

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8

How can I have the option of selecting between Win 8 and Ubuntu on my Win 8 machine?  Also, would appreciate any advice from those who have achieved this and running it successfully.
Thnx in advance...

Comment: Just install and follow the default options.

Answer (score 1):

You can install UBUNTU as fresh install by partitioning the Disks or the better way http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer   . When you switch on your pc you will be asking to choose OS to use.